# Randomly assign list items to Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drag and drop program, the code is down below. Now, I have been trying for a while to get my 'Simulate to the next round!' to take `.node7`, `.node8`, `.node9`, `.node10`, `.node11`, & `.node12` id's of some of the `li`'s and randomly assign one to each column, or 'Team'. Anything would help! Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/xwq8995t/4/), and here is a snippet:

```js
    /* VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */
    var boxSizeArray = [14,14,14,14,14,14]; // Array indicating how many items there is rooom for in the right column ULs

    var arrow_offsetX = -5; // Offset X - position of small arrow
    var arrow_offsetY = 0;  // Offset Y - position of small arrow

    var arrow_offsetX_firefox = -6; // Firefox - offset X small arrow
    var arrow_offsetY_firefox = -13; // Firefox - offset Y small arrow

    var verticalSpaceBetweenListItems = 3;  // Pixels space between one <li> and next
                                                                                    // Same value or higher as margin bottom in CSS for #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul li,#dragContent li


    var indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow = false;   // Display arrow to indicate where object will be dropped(false = use rectangle)

    var cloneSourceItems = false;   // Items picked from main container will be cloned(i.e. "copy" instead of "cut").
    var cloneAllowDuplicates = true;        // Allow multiple instances of an item inside a small box(example: drag Student 1 to team A twice

    /* END VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */

    var dragDropTopContainer = false;
    var dragTimer = -1;
    var dragContentObj = false;
    var contentToBeDragged = false; // Reference to dragged <li>
    var contentToBeDragged_src = false;     // Reference to parent of <li> before drag started
    var contentToBeDragged_next = false;    // Reference to next sibling of <li> to be dragged
    var destinationObj = false;     // Reference to <UL> or <LI> where element is dropped.
    var dragDropIndicator = false;  // Reference to small arrow indicating where items will be dropped
    var ulPositionArray = new Array();
    var mouseoverObj = false;       // Reference to highlighted DIV

    var MSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0?true:false;
    var navigatorVersion = navigator.appVersion.replace(/.*?MSIE (\d\.\d).*/g,'$1')/1;


    var indicateDestinationBox = false;
    function getTopPos(inputObj)
    {
      var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
      while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
            if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
      }
      return returnValue;
    }

    function getLeftPos(inputObj)
    {
      var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
      while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
            if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;
      }
      return returnValue;
    }

    function cancelEvent()
    {
            return false;
    }
    function initDrag(e)    // Mouse button is pressed down on a LI
    {
            if(document.all)e = event;
            var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
            var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);

            dragTimer = 0;
            dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
            dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';
            contentToBeDragged = this;
            contentToBeDragged_src = this.parentNode;
            contentToBeDragged_next = false;
            if(this.nextSibling){
                    contentToBeDragged_next = this.nextSibling;
                    if(!this.tagName && contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling)contentToBeDragged_next = contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling;
            }
            timerDrag();
            return false;
    }

    function timerDrag()
    {
            if(dragTimer>=0 && dragTimer<10){
                    dragTimer++;
                    setTimeout('timerDrag()',10);
                    return;
            }
            if(dragTimer==10){

                    if(cloneSourceItems && contentToBeDragged.parentNode.id=='Available Players'){
                            newItem = contentToBeDragged.cloneNode(true);
                            newItem.onmousedown = contentToBeDragged.onmousedown;
                            contentToBeDragged = newItem;
                    }
                    dragContentObj.style.display='block';
                    dragContentObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
            }
    }

    function moveDragContent(e)
    {
            if(dragTimer<10){
                    if(contentToBeDragged){
                            if(contentToBeDragged_next){
                                    contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
                            }else{
                                    contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
                            }
                    }
                    return;
            }
            if(document.all)e = event;
            var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
            var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);


            dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
            dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';

            if(mouseoverObj)mouseoverObj.className='';
            destinationObj = false;
            dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
            if(indicateDestinationBox)indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
            var x = e.clientX + sl;
            var y = e.clientY + st;
            var width = dragContentObj.offsetWidth;
            var height = dragContentObj.offsetHeight;

            var tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX;
            var tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY;
            if(!document.all){
                    tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX_firefox;
                    tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY_firefox;
            }

            for(var no=0;no<ulPositionArray.length;no++){
                    var ul_leftPos = ulPositionArray[no]['left'];
                    var ul_topPos = ulPositionArray[no]['top'];
                    var ul_height = ulPositionArray[no]['height'];
                    var ul_width = ulPositionArray[no]['width'];

                    if((x+width) > ul_leftPos && x<(ul_leftPos + ul_width) && (y+height)> ul_topPos && y<(ul_topPos + ul_height)){
                            var noExisting = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI').length;
                            if(indicateDestinationBox && indicateDestinationBox.parentNode==ulPositionArray[no]['obj'])noExisting--;
                            if(noExisting<boxSizeArray[no-1] || no==0){
                                    dragDropIndicator.style.left = ul_leftPos + tmpOffsetX + 'px';
                                    var subLi = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI');

                                    var clonedItemAllreadyAdded = false;
                                    if(cloneSourceItems && !cloneAllowDuplicates){
                                            for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
                                                    if(contentToBeDragged.id == subLi[liIndex].id)clonedItemAllreadyAdded = true;
                                            }
                                            if(clonedItemAllreadyAdded)continue;
                                    }

                                    for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
                                            var tmpTop = getTopPos(subLi[liIndex]);
                                            if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
                                                    if(y<tmpTop){
                                                            destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
                                                            indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
                                                            subLi[liIndex].parentNode.insertBefore(indicateDestinationBox,subLi[liIndex]);
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                            }else{
                                                    if(y<tmpTop){
                                                            destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
                                                            dragDropIndicator.style.top = tmpTop + tmpOffsetY - Math.round(dragDropIndicator.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
                                                            dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }

                                    if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
                                            if(indicateDestinationBox.style.display=='none'){
                                                    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
                                                    ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
                                            }

                                    }else{
                                            if(subLi.length>0 && dragDropIndicator.style.display=='none'){
                                                    dragDropIndicator.style.top = getTopPos(subLi[subLi.length-1]) + subLi[subLi.length-1].offsetHeight + tmpOffsetY + 'px';
                                                    dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                                            }
                                            if(subLi.length==0){
                                                    dragDropIndicator.style.top = ul_topPos + arrow_offsetY + 'px'
                                                    dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                                            }
                                    }

                                    if(!destinationObj)destinationObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'];
                                    mouseoverObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].parentNode;
                                    mouseoverObj.className='mouseover';
                                    return;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    /* End dragging
    Put <LI> into a destination or back to where it came from.
    */
    function dragDropEnd(e)
    {
            if(dragTimer==-1)return;
            if(dragTimer<10){
                    dragTimer = -1;
                    return;
            }
            dragTimer = -1;
            if(document.all)e = event;


            if(cloneSourceItems && (!destinationObj || (destinationObj && (destinationObj.id=='Available Players' || destinationObj.parentNode.id=='Available Players')))){
                    contentToBeDragged.parentNode.removeChild(contentToBeDragged);
            }else{

                    if(destinationObj){
                            if(destinationObj.tagName=='UL'){
                                    destinationObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
                            }else{
                                    destinationObj.parentNode.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,destinationObj);
                            }
                            mouseoverObj.className='';
                            destinationObj = false;
                            dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
                            if(indicateDestinationBox){
                                    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
                                    document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
                            }
                            contentToBeDragged = false;
                            return;
                    }
                    if(contentToBeDragged_next){
                            contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
                    }else{
                            contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
                    }
            }
            contentToBeDragged = false;
            dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
            if(indicateDestinationBox){
                    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
                    document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);

            }
            mouseoverObj = false;

    }

    /*
    Preparing data to be saved
    */
    function saveDragDropNodes()
    {
            var saveString = "";
            var uls = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
            for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){       // LOoping through all <ul>
                    var lis = uls[no].getElementsByTagName('LI');
                    for(var no2=0;no2<lis.length;no2++){
                            if(saveString.length>0)saveString = saveString + ";";
                            saveString = saveString + uls[no].id + '|' + lis[no2].id;
                    }
            }

            document.getElementById('saveContent').innerHTML = '<h1 align="center">Ready to save the following team rosters:<\/h1> ' + saveString.replace(/;/g,'<br>');

    }

    function initDragDropScript()
    {
            dragContentObj = document.getElementById('dragContent');
            dragDropIndicator = document.getElementById('dragDropIndicator');
            dragDropTopContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer');
            document.documentElement.onselectstart = cancelEvent;;
            var listItems = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('LI');        // Get array containing all <LI>
            var itemHeight = false;
            for(var no=0;no<listItems.length;no++){
                    listItems[no].onmousedown = initDrag;
                    listItems[no].onselectstart = cancelEvent;
                    if(!itemHeight)itemHeight = listItems[no].offsetHeight;
                    if(MSIE && navigatorVersion/1<6){
                            listItems[no].style.cursor='hand';
                    }
            }

            var mainContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');
            var uls = mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
            itemHeight = itemHeight + verticalSpaceBetweenListItems;
            for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){
                    uls[no].style.height = itemHeight * boxSizeArray[no]  + 'px';
            }

            var leftContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems');
            var itemBox = leftContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];

            document.documentElement.onmousemove = moveDragContent; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div
            document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd;       // Mouse move event - moving draggable div

            var ulArray = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
            for(var no=0;no<ulArray.length;no++){
                    ulPositionArray[no] = new Array();
                    ulPositionArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(ulArray[no]);
                    ulPositionArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(ulArray[no]);
                    ulPositionArray[no]['width'] = ulArray[no].offsetWidth;
                    ulPositionArray[no]['height'] = ulArray[no].clientHeight;
                    ulPositionArray[no]['obj'] = ulArray[no];
            }

            if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
                    indicateDestinationBox = document.createElement('LI');
                    indicateDestinationBox.id = 'indicateDestination';
                    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
                    document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);


            }
    }

    window.onload = initDragDropScript;

    function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "Draft_Data.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("saveContent").innerHTML;
    a.click();
    }
```

```css
    body{
        font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, sans-serif;              /* Font to use */
    background-color:#E2EBED;
    }
    #footer{
        height:30px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:right;
        clear:both;
        padding-right:3px;
        background-color:#317082;
        margin-top:2px;
        width:1250px;
    }
    #footer form{
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:2px;
    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{        /* Main container for this script */
    width:250%;
    height:2250px;
    border:1px solid #317082;
    background-color:#FFF;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul{     /* General rules for all <ul> */
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    }

    #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer li,#dragContent li,li#indicateDestination{      /* Movable items, i.e. <LI> */
    list-style-type:none;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:0.9em;
    }

    li#indicateDestination{ /* Box indicating where content will be dropped - i.e. the one you use if you don't use arrow */
    border:1px dotted #600;
    background-color:#FFF;
    }


    /* LEFT COLUMN CSS */
    div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{   /* Left column "Available students" */

    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;

    /* CSS HACK */
    width: 180px;   /* IE 5.x */
    width/* */:/**/160px;   /* Other browsers */
    width: /**/160px;

    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems ul{   /* Left(Sources) column <ul> */
    height:2184px;

    }

    div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div{
    border:1px solid #999;
    }
    div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div ul{    /* Left column <ul> */
    margin-left:10px;       /* Space at the left of list - the arrow will be positioned there */
    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div p{        /* Heading above left column */
    margin:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:12px;
    background-color:#317082;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    /* END LEFT COLUMN CSS */

    #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer .mouseover{     /* Mouse over effect DIV box in right column */
    background-color:#E2EBED;
    border:1px solid #317082;
    }

    /* Start main container CSS */

    div#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer{ /* Right column DIV */
    width:1096px;
    float:left;
    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div{        /* Parent <div> of small boxes */
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    border:1px solid #999;

    /* CSS HACK */
    width: 172px;   /* IE 5.x */
    width/* */:/**/170px;   /* Other browsers */
    width: /**/170px;

    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div ul{
    margin-left:10px;
    }

    #dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div p{      /* Heading above small boxes */
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#317082;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    #dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer ul{ /* Small box in right column ,i.e <ul> */
    width:152px;
    height:80px;
    border:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    overflow:hidden;

    }

    #dragContent{   /* Drag container */
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    display:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:2000;
    }

    #dragDropIndicator{     /* DIV for the small arrow */
    position:absolute;
    width:7px;
    height:10px;
    display:none;
    z-index:1000;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
    div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{
    display:none;
    }
    body{
    background-color:#FFF;
    }
    img{
    display:none;
    }
    #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    }
    p{
    margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="footer">
        <form action="aPage.html" method="post">
            <input type="button" value="Simulate to next round!" /><input type="button" onclick="saveDragDropNodes();download()" value="Download" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer">
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Available Players
                </p>
                <ul id="Available Players">
                    <li id="node7">Player A
                    </li>
                    <li id="node8">Player B
                    </li>
                    <li id="node9">Player C
                    </li>
                    <li id="node10">Player D
                    </li>
                    <li id="node11">Player E
                    </li>
                    <li id="node12">Player F
                    </li>
                    <li id="node13">Player G
                    </li>
                    <li id="node14">Player H
                    </li>
                    <li id="node15">Player I
                    </li>
                    <li id="node16">Player J
                    </li>
                    <li id="node17">Player K
                    </li>
                    <li id="node18">Player L
                    </li>
                    <li id="node19">Player M
                    </li>
                    <li id="node20">Player N
                    </li>
                    <li id="node21">Player O
                    </li>
                    <li id="node22">Player P
                    </li>
                    <li id="node23">Player Q
                    </li>
                    <li id="node24">Player R
                    </li>
                    <li id="node25">Player S
                    </li>
                    <li id="node26">Player T
                    </li>
                    <li id="node27">Player U
                    </li>
                    <li id="node28">Player V
                    </li>
                    <li id="node29">Player W
                    </li>
                    <li id="node30">Player X
                    </li>
                    <li id="node31">Player Y
                    </li>
                    <li id="node32">Player Z
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer">
            <!-- ONE <UL> for each "room" -->
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team A
                </p>
                <ul id="box1">
                    <li id="node1">Captain A
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team B
                </p>
                <ul id="box2">
                    <li id="node2">Captain B
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team C
                </p>
                <ul id="box3">
                    <li id="node3">Captain C
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team D
                </p>
                <ul id="box4">
                    <li id="node4">Captain D
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team E
                </p>
                <ul id="box5">
                    <li id="node5">Captain E
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team F
                </p>
                <ul id="box6">
                    <li id="node6">Captain F
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <form action="aPage.html" method="post">
            <input type="button" value="Simulate to next round!" /><input type="button" onclick="saveDragDropNodes();download()" value="Download" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="dragContent"></ul>
    <div id="dragDropIndicator">
        <img src="images/insert.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="saveContent" align="center"></div>
```

Comment: `<ul id="Available Players">` is not valid HTML, an element can't have multiple ids. Remove the whitespace or rename the element altogether.

Comment: At least in theory that's what it supposed to be but it works perfectly fine with the White Space in my browser so no real reason for me to remove it... If you want to change it in your answer that's fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implying that you change `id="Available Players"` to `id="AvailablePlayers"`, that should work:

```
function shufflePlayers(amount=6) {
    var box = 1;
    var rnd = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*$('#AvailablePlayers li').length));
        $('#AvailablePlayers').children('li').eq(rnd).appendTo('#box'+box);
        if(box == 6) {
            box = 1;
        } else {
            box++;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the function being able to shuffle >6 players, also moved the declarations outside of the loop.

**EDIT 2:** Here's a version that accepts an array of team container IDs as a parameter:

```
function shufflePlayers(amount=6, teamsID=['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5', 'box6']) {
    var box = 0;
    var rnd = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*$('#AvailablePlayers li').length));
        $('#AvailablePlayers').children('li').eq(rnd).appendTo('#'+teamsID[box]);
        if(box == teamsID.length) {
            box = 0;
        } else {
            box++;
        }
    }
}
```

As is, this modified function will work without any parameters, but if you change the team boxes ids, then you need to pass them as an array: `shufflePlayers(6, ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Cyan', 'Magenta', 'Yellow'])`

**EDIT 3:** Another version of the function, this time it only picks random players from the first set with the size of `amount` (default is 6).

```
function shufflePlayers(amount=6, teamsID=['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5', 'box6']) {
    var box = 0;
    var rnd = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*(amount-i)));
        $('#AvailablePlayers').children('li').eq(rnd).appendTo('#'+teamsID[box]);
        if(box == teamsID.length) {
            box = 0;
        } else {
            box++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I have seen the code, but is it possible to only pick from the first 6 nodes, then the next 6 nodes in the list and so on?

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph I updated the answer with the third version of the script that does just that. I also updated it on the page I linked previously.

Comment: I compared the code between my code and your code and I found out that it was the JQuery after all. The bit of code you included in your code `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph In case if your application is ever used locally, I'd recommend avoiding CDN includes and instead download jQuery directly to the server.